# How to unblock outgoing HTTP and HTTPS traffic in iptables?

Tags: iptables, firewall

With the following iptable rules, I was unable to do an apt update and ping a website. Whats wrong with the rules? How to fix it? What is the exact rule to fix it?

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:325 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Remember, IPTables works on PACKETS and not Logical Connections. Every last packet except TCP port 325 is getting dropped from the incoming traffic.

Comment: Outgoing HTTP and HTTPS traffic is unblocked. The problem is that no rule lets the reply packets in. You probably want ESTABLISHED/RELATED rules.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Check out any `iptables` HOWTO or FAQ. For example, check out [this page](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/iptables-rules-examples/), specifically the rule to allow outgoing HTTPS and DNS. (Or do you want to allow all outbound connections to just work? If so, generate a similar rule for all ports, TCP and UDP.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the DROP rule in the INPUT chain. It's dropping virtually *all* traffic coming in to the machine, including responses to any traffic you send out.

Comment: Then how to block un-needed incoming traffic? The default policy to drop?

Comment: That's a completely different question. :)

Comment: Michael: the perfect "you're in a balloon" answer.  Upvote!